# How to disable "back" button on my mouse?

Tags: windows, mouse-buttons

I have bought Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000. It's working just as I want it except that "back" button on the left side. I constantly hit it with the thumb and browser goes back. I am not used to this behavior, since my older mouse didn't have such a button. I just want to get rid of it -- disable the button once and forever, so if I clicked it -- nothing should happen.

Comment: It's like people put these features in, then never notice how bad they are and go back to fix the product they made.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have the Microsoft IntelliPoint "Mouse Properties" installed? If not get over to [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ea22bd62-4873-406a-bbbe-c587d35a53bf) and download and then install it.

Once you have the first tab "Buttons" lets you configure the button actions. Just select then "Right side button" drop down and select "Disabled".

[image]

Click "OK" or "Apply" and you're done.

NOTE: "Back" is actually on the left side button, so just replace "right" with "left" in the above description if you really meant that button.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Here's screenshot: http://i40.tinypic.com/sxoppt.png

Comment: IntelliPoint was recently updated. Go to http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/downloads/default.mspx and select the correct version for your system

Comment: @Sergiy - sorry I can't help any further as I don't have IntelliPoint on the Windows 7 machine I'm using. Have you got the latest version? Or have you got the right version for your OS 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @ChrisF I have 64-bit Windows, so I have downloaded 64-bit version.
@Shevek They don't have my mouse in the dropdown list. :(

Comment: Intellipoint is not the answer for two reasons:
1) This problem also happens on non-Microsoft 4-button mice (it seems to be built into the generic HID driver)
2) Intellipoint software, even up to the latest version, actually causes shift keys to get randomly stuck (!) and lots of people have to uninstall it for this reason (happened to me)

Comment: @Shevek now they have my mouse in the list, but there is no driver - just Product Guide and other PDFs :)

Comment: While this didn't help me, I have found this answer to be the most comprehensive, so I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I wonder if anyone uses those buttons, annoying

Comment: Newer version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=24777

Comment: is not working for me, I'm using a wireless mouse and is not detected

Comment: How do I do this with a Lenovo mouse? The microsoft software says I don't have any Microsoft mouse installed

Answer (score 23):

I would like to throw out [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) as a more generic program. For example, I'm currently using a Dell mouse with a non-Dell computer, and they have decided to lock their mouse drivers to only install on their own computers. X-Mouse should work with [most mice](http://forums.highrez.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=194):

> The only real answer to that is to try it and see, but there are
>   several tell tales signs. If you have a 5 button (or more) mouse and
>   the 4th and 5th buttons perform back/next in your web browser then its
>   almost certain XMBC will work for the first 5 buttons (XMBC does not
>   support more than 5 buttons).
>
> All I can say for sure is it works with the first 5 buttons of my
>   Logitech MX518 Optical mouse, with or without the Logitech software
>   installed.
>
> It also works fine with my older (original) MS Intellimouse Optical
>   Mouse.

You can also define multiple layers, and application specific profiles. So, you can have it behave as a back button on every program except your browser.

The appropriate button and drop down box will highlight when a button is pressed. You can use that to figure out which button does what, but I found `Mouse Button 5` to be the back button on my mouse.

[[image: Screenshot of X-Mouse Button Control]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGAz7.png)

Comment: AW YEAH! Does the trick!

Comment: I find that if I map Mouse Button 4 to Mouse Button 4, this disables the back behaviour, yet I can still map the button in games... Thanks I've downloaded and donated. This also replaces my flipMouseWheel app... (I prefer Natural Scrolling)

Comment: Oh, yeah, this works perfectly.

Comment: Nice suggestion there Bob... thanks. @Marius - exactly the thing I want to do as well. disable back in the browser but use it for other things.

Comment: This still worked for me, using a generic (non-Microsoft) multi-button mouse, in 2020.

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10 (21H2) but caused mousewheel to stop working in at least one critical windows program

Comment: I have a Logitech G403, and I always hit the back/fwd buttons on the side.  I set Button4 & 5 to disabled, worked right away!  Great app!  Windows 10 21H2.

Comment: @DavidHoward FWIW with a G403 you should also be able to use Logitech G Hub to alter/disable buttons. It's more full-fat than this software but you may find some of the additional features useful (e.g. DPI control). Additionally I believe G Hub allows you to save profiles to the mouse hardware so they work even without the software running, on other computers, etc..

Answer (score 6):

I took a flat-head screwdriver and a pair of pliers and I used the flat-head screwdriver to pry up the offending button, then I used the pliers to get a hold of that bugger and pull it loose from the housing. It caused the housing around the left button to loosen a bit, but I managed to work it back into its original position and now the mouse works great.

This is a great mouse, but that back button is way too big and too easy to press. It would be nicer if it were further forward and about 1/5th it's manufactured length. It would be nice if the button actually had to be PRESSed to activate rather than just barely touched as you reach over--without looking--to grab the mouse in order to scroll down or something. Now that I've removed that button, it really is a great mouse.

Comment: Well, there's always a physical solution.

Comment: lol, thanks for this answer. I really had to laugh out :-D

Comment: +1 for the physical fix, which I wouldn't have thought of without your answer. I have a similar Logitech mouse - I opened it up, prised out the microswitches from underneath the Back and Forward buttons and tucked them away under the lid.  No damage done, reversible if I change my mind, and as a bonus, the buttons don't feel like they do anything - they have no click.

Comment: I'll admit, I was pretty frustrated and past the edge of my tolerances when I grabbed the screwdriver and pliers. But, that said, I still use the mouse every single day with absolute joy, and it doesn't bother me a bit that there's a hole in it where the button used to be. I posted this in March of 2012? So that's another 8 years of use and counting since posting my "physical solution."

Answer (score 1):

The X-Mouse Button Control V2.17 would work in Windows Ultimate. 
Tested and it works. It works for most Generic 4 to 5 button Mouse.

Double click on X-Mouse Button Control on your taskbar. 
in Layer 1 menu.

- Under the Mouse Button 4. Select disable on the drop down menu.
- Under the Mouse Button 5, Select disable also.

Then click ok.
The mouse back and forward buttons will no longer work.

Comment: There is already an answer to this question suggesting x-mouse button control. Please post a new answer only if you have new information to share.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this in 2022, with a Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic mouse on Windows 10. IntelliMouse isn't a thing any more, and I didn't want to get into third-party things unless absolutely necessary. The download link I needed was in fact right there on the product page, but hidden away. As of today, the page has two tabs, "Overview" and "Tech specs", and the downloads are at the very bottom of "Tech specs". The download will give you an app called "Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center" which allows remapping or disabling the function of any button on any Microsoft mouse.

Comment: Just a heads up - that program only works with newer mice/keyboards - it doesn't detect older ones like my Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000 and won't allow access to any settings at all unless it detects a supported product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I'm going to try the MS software first because I am actually using a MS Intellimouse. I may try the X-Mouse program if I have any issues with it though. The most recent version of MS Intllipoint that I can find is 8.2 but download links seem to be broken on the MS website for the 64 bit version at the moment. I searched and found another source with a straight forward download from a 3rd party site. Check it out if you're having the same issues as I am. https://www.techspot.com/drivers/driver/file/information/15454/

Update: I gave the Microsoft Intellipoint software I linked above a shot and it seems to work great on my 64 bit Windows 10 system. It's worth noting though that I use a Microsoft Intellimouse so I can't speak to how well it will work on other brands. Also at the time of this writing, I have not had any issues with this software breaking or causing issue with the shift key, but should it, I will return with an update.