# Mouse wheel stuck down, how to remap a broken button.

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

My mouse wheel is pressed inside and stuck. I can't seem to fix it. I am not able to get a new mouse at short terms either.

I have the feeling the middle mouse button is pressed continuously which is disabling me to work properly since it recognizes a single left or right mouse press for a double press with the middle button.

So is there a way to disable the middle button and scroll-wheel in windows to fix this issue until I have a new mouse?  I do not have the original drivers, it's a basic Microsoft plug and play usb mouse.

Comment: There is software you can download where you can configure what each button on your mouse does: http://superuser.com/questions/122528/how-to-disable-back-button-on-my-mouse

Comment: To add to Erik's answer: Unplug the mouse and use the keyboard to navigate. (E.g. <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> to open the start menu, then use the cursors to go to the control panel. Pree <kbd>Return</kbd> to open the control panel. Etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try some software to remap mouse button events:

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Also, mice can be taken apart, the screws might be covered with stickers, but they should be there:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qf52mE0HKI

When the mouse is in pieces, remove the mouse wheel assembly completely and clean out the gunk in it which may un-click it, then put it back together.

Answer (score 1):

Try [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) it can remap almost any button or key.